# PHP, How do I calculate multiple arguments of the same thing in a switch statement?

Tags: php, variables, foreach, substring, argv

I'm making a time converter in PHP that converts time from days, hours, minutes to seconds. And I need to use `argv` and switch statements. However it doesn't really convert multiple of the same argument. For example: input: `php time.php 2m 2m`
Output: `120 Seconds`. It's suppose to be 240 seconds.

I have tried using `count`. That does work, but only if you have the same arguments. When you have hours, minutes days and seconds. together it wont work. Here's my current code and it works with each own argument

```
<?php

//variables
$time = implode(" ", $argv);
$timearray = (explode(" ", $time));
$timeday = 0;
$timehour = 0;
$timemin = 0;
$timesec = 0;
//loop
foreach ($timearray as $time) {
    $letter = substr($time, -1);
    $aantal = substr($time, 0, -1);
    //switch
    switch ($letter) {
        case "d":
            $timeday = $aantal * 86400;
            break;
        case "u":
            $timehour = $aantal * 3600;
            break;
        case "m":
            $timemin = $aantal * 60;
            break;
        case "s":
            $timesec = $aantal * 1;
            break;
    }
    $total = ($timeday + $timehour + $timemin + $timesec);
}
echo $total  . " Seconds" . PHP_EOL;
```

Not sure how I can fix it.

Comment: You are _overwriting_ each of your `$timeXYZ` variables in your cases there, instead of _adding_ to their current value. Make each of those `=` a `+=` instead.

Comment: I think  you need a `+=` in this line `$total += ($timeday + $timehour + $timemin + $timesec);` And that means you will have to initialise `$total = 0` before thr foreach

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this quite a lot:

```
<?php
array_shift($argv);

$total = 0;
foreach ($argv as $time) {
    $letter = substr($time, -1);
    $aantal = substr($time, 0, -1);

    switch ($letter) {
        case "d":
            $total += $aantal * 86400;
            break;
        case "u":
            $total += $aantal * 3600;
            break;
        case "m":
            $total += $aantal * 60;
            break;
        case "s":
            $total += $aantal * 1;
            break;
    }
}
echo $total  . " Seconds" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: You could put the factors in an array: `$factor = ["d" => 86400, "u" => 3600, "m" => 60, "s" =>1];` and simplify even further. Oh, the question specifies that the code "needs" to use the `switch`. How weird.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Sure, all sorts of different approaches are possible. There is no right or wrong. I, personally, would always use a library for such things to prevent making the same mistakes again thousands made before my attempt ...